# Python Tkinter canvas class inheritance

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

Using Tkinter 8.6, Python 3.7.3:

A friendly user here instructed me on how to have an image act like a button by the way of creating an `Imgbutton` class that is a subclass of Tkinter `Canvas`.

I have some questions regarding this code, here is the simplified version of it:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Imgbutton(tk.Canvas):

    def __init__(self, master=None, image=None, command=None, **kw):

        super(Imgbutton, self).__init__(master=master, **kw)
```

```
        self.set_img = self.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw', image=image)
```

```
        self.bind_class( self, '<Button-1>',
                    lambda _: self.config(relief='sunken'), add="+")

        self.bind_class( self, '<ButtonRelease-1>',
                    lambda _: self.config(relief='groove'), add='+')

        self.bind_class( self, '<Button-1>',
                    lambda _: command() if command else None, add="+")
```

Questions:

1. When I create an `Imgbutton` object, the separated line above gets executed but I do not understand why.
2. Does the `self.set_img` correspond to an object of `Imgbutton`or `tk.Canvas` class?
3. Is there any point here where an actual canvas is created? I believed you need to create a canvas before you can add anything to it.

---

This part might be unneccessary to mention but here I am creating an `Imgbutton`object:

```
root = tk.Tk()

but_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='button.png')

but = Imgbutton(root, image=but_img, width=but_img.width(),
            height=but_img.height(), borderwidth=2, highlightthickness=0)
but.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `self.set_img` is a tag returned from method `create_image` which is of class `Canvas` that I inherited to `Imgbutton` so it means all the features (methods) of `Canvas` can be used in `Imgbutton` class as well. When you create an instance of `Imgbutton` the `Canvas` creates itself, basically `Imgbutton` is Canvas just with some modifications.

Comment: Take the lesson [Python - Object Oriented](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm). **Q-2**: `self.set_img` is the `iid`, returnd from [`.create_image(...`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_image-method), of the `image` object inside the `Canvas` object.

Comment: @Saad: `tag` isn't quite the right terminology. `create_image` returns an id. Ids are unique, and they are integers. A tag cannot be an integer, nor string composed only of digits.

Comment: @BryanOakley: You're right `tag` is a parameter which takes string and they can be the same for multiple canvas items where as `id` is an unique integer to each item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I create an Imgbutton object, the separated line above gets executed but I do not understand why.

It's executed because it's part of the code. I'm not sure why you think it wouldn't be called. If you don't want it to be called, move it outside of the `__init__` method.

> Does the self.set_img correspond to an object of Imgbuttonor tk.Canvas class?

`self` refers to the instance of the `Imgbutton` class. `set_img` will be the identifier returned by the canvas when it creates the object on the canvas.

> Is there any point here where an actual canvas is created?

Yes. `Imgbutton` is the canvas. That is how inheritance works: `Imgbutton` is a   `Canvas`, with some enhancements. It gets created when you do `but = Imgbutton(...)`. Though, perhaps a bit more accurately the actual canvas is created when you call `super`, which tells tkinter to create the object.