# Is there a way to get custom shaped buttons in Tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Is there a way to get buttons in Tkinter that are a different shape than rectangle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All widgets in `tkinter` have a rectangular shape. So for example a "real" triangular widget is *not possible*.

But you could *simulate* one in two basic ways.

1. Use a `Label` with an image on it, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54382726/1219295).
2. Using a `Canvas` widget as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55893187/python-tkinter-canvas-class-inheritance).